# Windows workflow 4.0 Persistence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Would someone please explain to me why i would need to persist a workflow in a database. Please am just trying to understand the concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow are often long running in nature, like weeks or months. And keeping them in memory means you can't recycle the application or machine. By saving the state to disk, ie database, you can restart the process and machine. Also keeping worklflows in memory when they aren't doing anything just wasts memory resources and thus hinders scalability. Finally saving state in a database means we can restart the workflow from that state so it also helps when error handling.

Comment: does this mean that using a workflow is recommended for an application that is used to do normal approval. Example The approval of leave within a given organisation??

Comment: That would be an example where workflow would make perfect sense.

Comment: ok..but in this case would i require any persistence for such a workflow and why.

Comment: Do you require it? Guess not if you make sure IIS or your custom host never recycles and you never restart the machine while there are active workflows. But if you are realistic, yes you would for the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: Of course you want persistence. Rememeber, it you were to write this without WF, you would still have persistence in that you would have a table called something like "LeaveRequest", probably with some kind of status field. Each action would pull and push to this table. With WF, the interactions would pull and push to the workflow instead. Once it hits an idle point (post request, pre approval, for example), it will auto persist itself due a binary serialized form until the next action is taken.